# no easy way with records in F#?

Tags: f#, instantiation, record

In F# I can do this:

```
type coord = float * float  //Type for a 2D-float-tupple
let myDepthCurve1 = { coords = [(1., 2.); (3., 4.)]; depth = 9.4 }
```

but I can't do this:

```
type coord = { longitude : float; latitude : float } //Type for a 2D-float-record
let myDepthCurve1 = { coords = [(longitude = 1., latitude = 2.); (longitude = 3., latitude = 4.)]; depth = 9.4 }
```

Is it true that I can't create my depthurve in one go when the fields in the coord type record are labeled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `{}` for records, not `()`. I.e.:

```
type coord = { longitude : float; latitude : float } //Type for a 2D-float-record
let myDepthCurve1 = {
     coords = [ { longitude = 1.; latitude = 2. };
                { longitude = 3.; latitude = 4. }];
     depth = 9.4 }
```

Comment: except that it should be ; rather than , in the expression {longitude = 1., latitude = 2.}
Is there any systematic pattern in the usage of , and ; in F#?

Comment: Fixed. The pattern is simple - comma is a tuple-producing operator (note that it doesn't require parentheses), so everything else has to use semicolon to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be fine if you used curly braces instead of parentheses to construct the "inline" record expression.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a type like this:

type x = { coords : coord list ; depth : float };;

You could write this:

let myDepthCurve1 = { coords = [{longitude = 1.; latitude = 2.}; 
                                   {longitude = 3.; latitude = 4.}]; 
     depth = 9.4 };;

Comment: Thanks guys. Small detail, big difference.